# User input JavaScript eval with variable declarations

Tags: javascript, command-line, firebug, eval

As part of a homework I am trying to implement a JavaScript console similar to the one available in Firebug in a browser environment. From what I've picked up, `eval()` seems to be the easiest way to do this. However, my code runs into some problems on even very basic user input. For example:

```
var number = 5;
```

Causes a syntax error rather than just evaluating to `undefined` like it would in Firebug. Because of this I can't seem to declare variables at all inside the eval string. If I do something more simple like:

```
3 + 4 * Math.PI
```

It works correctly. I have tried to find an example of someone using `eval()` on a string containing a variable declaration, and I just can't seem to find anyone doing this.

Do I need to parse the user input completely using regular expressions before compiling it into a new string for `eval()`?

Can `eval()` understand semicolons as line breaks? I can't find people using these either.

```
function runMiniFirebug() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("user-input").value;
    try {
        var userOutput = eval('(' + userInput + ')');
        document.getElementById("js-output").innerHTML += '<p class="input">>>>' + userInput + '<p>';
        document.getElementById("js-output").innerHTML += '<p class="ouput">' + userOutput + '<p>';
    }
    catch(error) {
        document.getElementById("js-output").innerHTML += '<p class="input">>>>' + userInput + '<p>';
        document.getElementById("js-output").innerHTML += '<p class="error">' + error.message + '<p>';
    }
}
```

EDIT:
So it seems the added parens are causing the error. This is a section from my instructors slides. Is the information incorrect, or am I just interpreting it incorrectly?

> Strings that are delimited with { ... }
>
> –  You have to add extra parens so that JavaScript will know that the
>   braces are for object literals, not for delimiting statements.
>
> •  It never hurts to do this, so add parens routinely
>
> –  var test2 = "{ firstName: 'Jay', lastName: 'Sahn' }";
>
> –  var person = eval("(" + test2 + ")");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var userOutput = eval('(' + userInput + ')');
```

Why are you wrapping with parentheses? This creates the statement

```
(var number = 5;)
```

which is invalid syntax.

Simply remove the `'(' +` and `+ ')'`.

---

As for your edit, that is referring to only evaluating single **expressions**. `var number = 5;` is not an expression, nor is `alert(1 + 1); alert(2 + 2);`. Wrapping either in parentheses will cause an error.

Comment: Going to add the why to this in my question since it's formatted. Removing them does seem to fix my problem...

Comment: @sage88 Yes, that should be what the user inputs, not done by you. What if someone really wants a block, like `{alert(1+1); alert(2+2);}`?

Comment: Added the reason for why I had them to my original question, am I interpreting his statement incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Thinking about wrapping multiple lines of javascript in parens makes it obvious why my original code could never work.